# Getting segmentation fault using malloc for 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

I had initialized a 2D array using malloc for adjacency matrix of a large graph and then initializing each index with 0 or 1 depending upon the edge list.But I m getting a segmentation fault. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int MAX = 50000;
void clustering(int **adj);

int main()
{
  int i, j, k;  
  FILE *ptr_file1;
  int **adj;

  adj = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*MAX);
  for(i=0;i<MAX;++i)
  adj[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*MAX);

  struct adjacency
  {
     int node1;
     int node2;
  };
  struct adjacency a;

  ptr_file1 = fopen("Email-Enron.txt","r"); //Opening file containing edgelist of approx  37000 nodes.

  if (!ptr_file1)
    return 1;

  while(fscanf(ptr_file1,"%d %d",&a.node1, &a.node2)!=EOF)
  {
     adj[a.node1][a.node2] = 1;                   //Getting segmentation fault here   
     adj[a.node2][a.node1] = 1; 

  printf("adj[%d][%d] = %d   adj[%d][%d] = %d\n",a.node1,a.node2,adj[a.node1][a.node2],a.node2,a.node1,adj[a.node2][a.node1]);  
  }
  clustering(adj);
  return (0);
 }
```

Here is my output

```
......
......
adj[85][119] = 1   adj[119][85] = 1
adj[85][154] = 1   adj[154][85] = 1
adj[85][200] = 1   adj[200][85] = 1
adj[85][528] = 1   adj[528][85] = 1
adj[85][604] = 1   adj[604][85] = 1
adj[85][661] = 1   adj[661][85] = 1
adj[85][662] = 1   adj[662][85] = 1
adj[85][686] = 1   adj[686][85] = 1
adj[85][727] = 1   adj[727][85] = 1
adj[85][1486] = 1   adj[1486][85] = 1
adj[85][1615] = 1   adj[1615][85] = 1
adj[85][2148] = 1   adj[2148][85] = 1
adj[85][2184] = 1   adj[2184][85] = 1
adj[85][2189] = 1   adj[2189][85] = 1
adj[85][2190] = 1   adj[2190][85] = 1
adj[85][2211] = 1   adj[2211][85] = 1
adj[85][3215] = 1   adj[3215][85] = 1
adj[85][4583] = 1   adj[4583][85] = 1
adj[85][4585] = 1   adj[4585][85] = 1
adj[85][4586] = 1   adj[4586][85] = 1
adj[85][4589] = 1   adj[4589][85] = 1
adj[85][4590] = 1   adj[4590][85] = 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What is wrong here.Pls help...

Comment: Print node1 and node2 before the line where it crashes, and tell us what they are when the crash happens.  Or use a debugger.  :)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: I'm all for using `new` instead of `malloc()` in C++, but not one line of this code is actually C++, it's C.  :)

Comment: If you code in C: Don't mention C++. read documentation of [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html). Always test return value of `malloc`. Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). **Use the debugger** (`gdb`). Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: And at all: dont cast malloc()'s return value in C.

Comment: you do not need int for storing 1 or 0 value, you need char or bit map, if you want, i will explain, how use a bit map

Comment: Siddharth can you confirm which language you are using? You tagged the question as C++; John Zwinck changed the tag. C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: @JohnZwinck every line of this code is C++. If your C++ compiler does not compile it then your compiler is broken (other than the missing implementation for `clustering`).

Comment: Siddharth: (1) check result of malloc for NULL, (2) change loop to check `== 2` instead of `!= EOF`, (3) check a.node1 and a.node2 are in range [0, MAX) before using them

Comment: @IvanIvanovich :  Pls explain how to use bitmap here..

Answer (score 2):

The problem must be coming from the memory allocation. On a classic computer, `sizeof(int)` is 4 and `sizeof(int*)` can be 4 (32 bits OS) or 8 (64 bits OS).

There, you are first allocating the room for 50000 pointers, thus 50000*4 = 200000 bytes at least.

Then, you loop through this in order to allocate 50.000*50.000*4 = 10.000.000.000 bytes = 10 GB !

Since you do *NOT* check on `malloc()` return value, my guess is that at some point in this loop :

```
for(i=0;i<MAX;++i)
    adj[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*MAX);
```

`malloc` always returns `NULL`. Let denote M such an index. In your case I can guess that M ≥ 4591.

Later, when reading the data from your file, you try to access a `NULL` pointer if M ≤ `a.node1`.

By the way, you could allocate 2D arrays like this :

```
int **array, i;
if(NULL == (array = malloc(sizeof(int*)*MAX))) {
    printf("Oops, not enough memory ...\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
if(NULL == (array[0] = malloc(sizeof(int)*MAX*MAX))) {
    printf("Oops, not enough memory ...\n");
    free(array);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
for(i = 1; i < MAX; i++)
    array[i] = array[0]+i;
// At this point, array is ready to use.
do_stuff();
// When you are done, freeing the memory is not tiresome :
free(array[0]);
free(array);
```

*(Notice that in C, you never cast the return of malloc.)*

What is the difference between this allocation and yours ? In yours, each `adj[i]` point to a dynamically allocated chunk of data. As a consequence, there is little chance that these chunks of data will be contiguous in memory. In the one I propose, there is only 2 memory allocations and in the end the chunks of data pointed by `adj[i]` and `adj[i+1]` are contiguous.

**NB :**

> adjacency matrix of a large graph

Although adjacency matrix is a perfectly valid way to  store a graph in memory, when the graph tends to be large, you should use adjacency list instead.

Comment: I tried what u had provided here. But it is giving  this error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
         raw = malloc(sizeof(int)*MAX*MAX);
invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int**’ [-fpermissive]
  array = malloc(sizeof(int*)*MAX);
                               ^

Comment: @SiddharthUbana are you compiling C code with a C++ compiler ?!

Comment: I am using cc compiler. here is compilation command:                cc clustering.cpp

Comment: @SiddharthUbana, why is your source file a .cpp if you are coding using C ?

Comment: I changed the extension to .c and it compiled successfully. Also I had checked the return value of malloc.But it didn't work out yet.

Comment: @SiddharthUbana, you have __not__ enough memory to store `50000*50000`  int ... Btw I added the classic `malloc()` error checking just to be sure we're on the same page.

Comment: I changed the extension to .c and it compiled successfully. Also I had checked the return value of malloc.But it isn't worked out yet.  Can you suggest me now how can I access a node at index array[i][j] after implementing your solution above.  :)

Comment: @SiddharthUbana, you use `array[i][j]`, just like you used `adj[i][j]` in your original code.

Comment: "you should allocate 2-D arrays like this"  - you *could* allocate them like that but it is not correct to say *should*.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, you must be thinking of some cases where a big chunk of data can't be allocated at once ? In that case yes, the other fashion would indeed be a must.

Comment: @Rerito no it wouldn't.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, so you are thinking about something else. I'm interested to know what in order to see where I can be wrong

Comment: @Rerito I already did exactly what u had suggested here. But neither of the if blocks are executing... means it is not returning a NULL pointer but further still it is giving the same error.  :(

Comment: There is more than one way to allocate an array and the programmer can choose whichever one he or she prefers; both of these methods work.  One technique may have advantages over the other technique in some applications, and the other may have advantages in other applications. And in many applications there would be no noticeable difference.

Comment: @SiddharthUbana, then I suggest you follow Paul R's answer and add a `printf()` before the error to see which indexes produce the said error :)

Answer (score 1):

`50000 * 50000` ints is quite a lot. Namely, it is 9Gb memory for 4 byte integer. Are you quite sure you get all the memory allocated?

Add a check:

```
if (!adj[i])
   return 2;
```

Note that you *have* to compile for x64 and run on an x64 machine for it to work. Most probably you don't need that much data.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, there is no need to allocate an array of pointers pointing to arrays of ints. Just allocate one single array of ints with the size of MAX*MAX.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, add a debug printf *before* the error:

```
  while(fscanf(ptr_file1,"%d %d",&a.node1, &a.node2)!=EOF)
  {
     printf("%d %d\n", a.node1, a.node2);

     adj[a.node1][a.node2] = 1;                   //Getting segmentation fault here   
     adj[a.node2][a.node1] = 1; 
  }
```

That way you can see if your array indices are out of range before your program crashes.

This is just a quick fix for debugging purposes though - really you should have proper error checking:

```
  while(fscanf(ptr_file1,"%d %d",&a.node1, &a.node2)!=EOF)
  {
     if (a.node1 >= MAX || a.node2 >= MAX)
     {
         fprintf(stderr, "range error: a.node1 = %d, a.node2 = %d\n", a.node1, a.node2);
         exit(1);
     }

     adj[a.node1][a.node2] = 1;                   //Getting segmentation fault here   
     adj[a.node2][a.node1] = 1; 
  }
```

Comment: I had already checked it. It is not going out of range after the crash point.

Comment: OK - so what were the values of `a.node1` and `a.node2` when it crashed ?

Answer (score 0):

for comment. use one dimensions  bitmap, but one dimension may be use as two dimention and can be useful for graphs

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX 4000000

unsigned char *bitmapinit(int n);
unsigned char chkbit(unsigned char *map, int n);
void setbit(unsigned char *map, int n);
void unsetbit(unsigned char *map, int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        unsigned int i;
        unsigned char *bitmap = bitmapinit(MAX);
        if (!bitmap) {
                perror("malloc: ");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
                setbit(bitmap, i);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < MAX; i += 5) {
                 unsetbit(bitmap, i);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
                printf("bit #%d = %d\n", i, (chkbit(bitmap, i))?1:0);
        }
        return 0;
}
unsigned char *bitmapinit(int n)
{
        return calloc(sizeof(unsigned char), n / 8 + 1);
}
unsigned char chkbit(unsigned char *map, int n)
{
        return (unsigned char)map[n / 8] & (1 << (n % 8));
}
void setbit(unsigned char *map, int n)
{
        map[n / 8] = map[n / 8] | (1 << (n % 8));
}
void unsetbit(unsigned char *map, int n)
{
        map[n / 8] = map[n / 8] & ~(1 << (n % 8));
}
```

I can explain how it is used for graphs, if you need.

space-saving 8x. For matrix from 50000 x 50000 you need ~300MB, graph can be oriented, but not multiply-linked

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>    
#include <errno.h>

#define ROW 50
#define COL 55

unsigned int *bitmapinit(int, int);
bool chkbit(unsigned int *, int, int, int);
void setbit(unsigned int *, int, int, int);
void unsetbit(unsigned int *, int, int, int);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    unsigned int *bitmap = bitmapinit(ROW, COL);
    if (!bitmap) {
        perror("malloc: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i+=2)
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j+=2)
            setbit(bitmap, i, j, COL);    

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            printf("%d ",(chkbit(bitmap, i, j, COL)) ? 1 : 0);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++)
            setbit(bitmap, i, j, COL);

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i += 3)
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j += 3)
            unsetbit(bitmap, i, j, COL);    

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            printf("%d ",(chkbit(bitmap, i, j, COL)) ? 1 : 0);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned int *bitmapinit(int row, int col) //n it is ROWS, m it is COLUMNS
{
    return calloc(sizeof(unsigned int), (row * col) / 32 + 1);
}
bool chkbit(unsigned int *map, int row, int col, int n)
{
    return map[(row * n + col) / 32] & (1 << (row * n + col) % 32);
}
void setbit(unsigned int *map, int row, int col, int n)
{
    map[(row * n + col) / 32] = map[(row * n + col) / 32] | (1 << (row * n + col) % 32);
}
void unsetbit(unsigned int *map, int row, int col, int n)
{
    map[(row * n + col) / 32] = map[(row * n + col) / 32] & ~(1 << (row * n + col) % 32);
}
```

program is not complicated, in fact it is a 2-dimensional array, but each elements of the array can be set to only 0 or 1

but with values ​​50000 * 50000 will work for a long time

respectively, to set the bit XY you need to call the `setbit(unsigned char *map, int Y, int X, int LenOfRow);`
to clear the bit XY `unsetbit(unsigned char *map, int Y, int X, int LenOfRow);`
and obtain the values ​​of bit XY `checkbit(unsigned char *map, int Y, int X, int LenOfRow);`

once again remind you that the value of `LenOfRow` should not change within a one array

Comment: pls explain further for graphs also.

Comment: well, a few hours later, I'm busy

Comment: in fact, any array is a linear space of bytes, so any linear space of bytes can be represented as a multidimensional array. With bitmap few harder

Answer (score 0):

As the others have noted, your problem is very likely the sheer size of your 2D array. So you have three options:

1. Optimize the size of your adjacency matrix. You can cut the memory consumption by a factor of four (on most systems) by using `int8_t` instead of `int`. You can cut it by another factor of eight by using individual bits of the integers that comprise the matrix. That's a factor of 32 which should be enough to get your matrix down to manageable size.

   You could use accessors like this:

   ```
   void setAdjacent(int32_t** matrix, int x, int y) {
       matrix[x][y/32] |= (1 << (y & 31));
   }

   int isAdjacent(int32_t** matrix, int x, int y) {
       return matrix[x][y/32] & (1 << (y & 31));
   }
   ```
2. Exploit the fact that your adjacency matrix is sparse. For each node, store a list of all the other nodes that it is adjacent to.
3. Buy more RAM.

---

You can also use a true 2D array like this:

```
int32_t (*matrix)[MAX] = malloc(MAX*sizeof(*matrix));
```

This avoids the hassle of allocating an array for each line, and avoids the overhead of one pointer indirection. You would just need to change the signature of the accessors accordingly, their contents does not change at all.

Comment: using `int (*matrix)[MAX] = malloc(MAX*sizeof(*matrix));` gives me a warning: `warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]`

Comment: @Zelphir I have just double checked the correctness of that line using both `gcc` and `g++`. Since I didn't manage to reproduce your warning, I am quite certain that the error must be somewhere else, that the `malloc()` call itself is correct as I gave it. Things you might want to check: 1. Is `MAX` really an integer constant? 2. Did you terminate the preceding statement with a `;`? 3. Did you include the header for `malloc()` (`#include <stdlib.h>`)? 4. Is there any typo in your code?